# Animate scroll left using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the current code I have for clicking buttons and having it scroll through and change a few things.

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event) {
    $('.panel h1').stop().fadeOut(200);
    $('.panel p').stop().fadeOut(200);

    $(".scroll").css({"background": "none", "color": "#B1B1B1"});

    $(this).css({"background": "#00709C", "color": "#fff"});

    event.preventDefault();

    $('.scroll-menu').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $('.scroll-menu').scrollLeft() + $(this.hash).offset().left
    }, 1200);
    $('.panel h1').delay( 900 ).fadeIn(500);
    $('.panel p').delay( 900 ).fadeIn(500);
});
```

I got a little help, so actually I'm confused as to what `$(this.hash).offset().left` is referring to.

Also, can anyone give me an idea as to how to automatically animate this without an on click?  For instance, this does NOT work.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.scroll-menu').stop().animate({
       scrollLeft: $('.scroll-menu').scrollLeft() + $(this.hash).offset().left
    }, 1200);
    $('.panel h1').delay( 900 ).fadeIn(500);
    $('.panel p').delay( 900 ).fadeIn(500);
    }, 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/afzVe/617/

and the relevant code:

```
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $('#test').css('left')
    }, 800, function() {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollLeft: 0
        }, 800);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an `anchor` tag like one below:

```
<a href="#foo" class="scroll">Some anchor</a>
```

`this.hash` on `anchor click` will return `"#foo"` which is also a valid `ID` selector. Hence `$(this.hash)` is the same as `$("#foo")` and will select the element with `ID` - `foo` and `$(this.hash).offset().top` basically returns `top` of element `#foo`

Regarding your 2nd question its quite unclear as to on what instance you want to `animate` automatically but still in your `setInterval` since you are referring `$(this.hash)` and since its not a valid `element` there you can first try keeping element in variable and then apply the `hash` functionality like one below:

```
var elem=$(".scroll");//store it globally

setInterval(function() {
    $('.scroll-menu').stop().animate({
       scrollLeft: $('.scroll-menu').scrollLeft() + $(elem.hash).offset().left
    }, 1200);
    $('.panel h1').delay( 900 ).fadeIn(500);
    $('.panel p').delay( 900 ).fadeIn(500);
}, 3600);
```